# Convert string into nested objects and arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, contentful

I am in a project where the previous guy did some strange routing and basically I get slugs from contentful in the form of strings which I put in an array `["/api/", "/docs/getting-started/", "/docs/, "/plugin/", "/plugin/user/", "/plugin/profile/"......]`

Now I need to convert it in the form of an array

```
let cleanedSidebarContents = [{
              title:null,
              pages:[
                     {title:"api",
                      path:"/api/"
                      },
                     {title:"docs",
                      path:"/docs/"
                      },
                      {title:"plugin",
                      path:"/plugin/"
                      },
                     ]
               },
             {
              title:"plugin",
              pages:[
                     {title:"user",
                      path:"/plugin/user/"
                      },
                     {title:"profile",
                      path:"/plugin/profile/"
                      },
                     ]
               },
              {
              title:"docs",
              pages:[
                     {title:"getting-started",
                      path:"/plugin/getting-started/"
                      },
                     ]
               }
]
```

So currently what I am doing is this -

```
 //-------Format sidebar data--------------->
    let cleanedSidebarContents = [];
    (function cleanSidebarContents() {

        let sideBarContentsContentful = [];
        cleanContentfulEdges.forEach(edge => {
            let slug = edge.node.slug;
            //split string into titles and remove empty spaces
            let routeMapArray = slug.split("/").filter(x => x != "");
            if (routeMapArray.length > 1) {
                sideBarContentsContentful.push({
                    title: routeMapArray[0],
                    page: {
                        title: routeMapArray[routeMapArray.length - 1],
                        path: edge.node.slug
                    }
                });
            } else {
                sideBarContentsContentful.push({
                    title: null,
                    page: {
                        title: routeMapArray[routeMapArray.length - 1],
                        path: edge.node.slug
                    }
                });
            }
        });

        let titles = [];
        for (let i = 0; i < sideBarContentsContentful.length; i++) {
            titles.push(sideBarContentsContentful[i].title);
        }
        //clean duplicate entries
        titles = titles.filter(function (item, index, inputArray) {
            return inputArray.indexOf(item) === index;
        });
        titles.sort();

        titles.map(item => {
            cleanedSidebarContents.push({
                title: item,
                pages: []
            })
        });

        sideBarContentsContentful.forEach(item => {
            for (let i = 0; i < cleanedSidebarContents.length; i++) {
                if(cleanedSidebarContents[i].title === item.title){
                    cleanedSidebarContents[i].pages.push(item.page)
                }
            }
        });
    }());
    //----------------------------------------->
```

I am first splitting all strings and putting the titles in a titles array then removing duplicates and mapping data accordingly.

I just feel like this is really bad code and there is a better way I just cannot figure out.

Comment: HI, I think this is the wrong place for your question. It's more a code-review related question. Here we ask to some specific topics that could be helpful also to others. Try here: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could create a `mapper` object which maps the objects in the output with the `title` in the root of each object. `split` at the `/` to get all the chunks of path. `.filter(Boolean)` removes all the empty string created from beginning and end of the string. If there is only one match, then it belongs to the default `null` object. Else, use the first key in the `matches` as a key in the accumulator.

```js
const input = ["/api/", "/docs/getting-started/", "/docs/", "/plugin/", "/plugin/user/", "/plugin/profile/"];

const mapper = input.reduce((acc, path) => {
  let matches = path.split(/\//).filter(Boolean),
      mapperKey = null;

  if (matches.length > 1)
    mapperKey = matches[0];

  if (!acc[mapperKey])
    acc[mapperKey] = { title: mapperKey, pages: [] };

  const title = matches.pop();
  acc[mapperKey].pages.push({ title, path });
  
  return acc;
}, {})

const output = Object.values(mapper);

console.log(output)
```

Comment: Thanks, it works, I don't know how but I will study it. Cheers!

Comment: @Jaykch the idea is to use the same object in the output array and the mapper object's value. For example, an object like `pluginObject = { title: "plugin", pages: [..] }` is created. And the same object's reference is used in `mapper["plugin"] = pluginObject` and `output.push(pluginObject )`. So, if you find a path that starts with "plugin", you simply push it to `mapper["plugin"].pages` array. This will also update the object in the output array because they are both poiting to the same object. You don;t have to go through the array and check if there is any object with the `title: "plugin"`

Comment: I've updated it to use `reduce` and simplified the regular expression to use split

Comment: Thank you, I looked at it now, so strange I thought I couldnt locate array[key] in javascript. Seems so stupid now. Thank you so much.